# Calibrated my camera using OpenCV. How do I apply the coefficients in output xml to my future projects

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

After calibrating my camera using the "chessboard" method. How do I implement/make use of the results given in the output xml file to my subsequent code? I'm not quite sure what the next step entails.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#results), referring to the coefficients outputted in your XML file:

> Add these values as constants to your program, call the [initUndistortRectifyMap](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#initundistortrectifymap) and the remap function to remove distortion and enjoy distortion free inputs for cheap and low quality cameras.